# Asymptotic notation: Once $j$ is $\Theta(\log \log n)$

Tags: asymptotics

In the paper [Wherefor Art Thou R3579X?](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~lars/www07-anon.pdf) they state at the end of page 5, while proving theorem 2.2, that "Once $j$ is $\Theta(\log \log n)$, each term in the sum is $O(1)$".

My question is now what does "Once $j$ is $\Theta(\log \log n)$" mean? Does this have a proper definition or is it just more abuse of asymptotic notation?

Answer (score 1):

My take on this is that there are real positive constants $a$ and $b$
such that
$$a \log \log n < j < b\log \log n $$

Evidently (since I have not read the original reference),
this will allow you to deduce
that the terms referred to are $O(1)$.

(Added a bit later)

If you want to keep this completely in terms of $O(...)$ notation,
both $j = O(\log \log n)$
and $\log \log n = O(j)$
hold.